# Datagrid, Index was out of range

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am taking value from Datagrid, storing it into textfield and dump the values into database via submit button and also i am calling the same table again for refreshing purpose on that button.But here i am getting an exception...

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   collection. Parameter name:Index

I have also another problem is that there is producing an extra row. why it is happening I cannot undertstand. And if i click that extra row, my program shows another exception.

Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
da.Fill(ds);
datagridAccepted.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

DataRowView row = (DataRowView)datagridDocSchedule.SelectedItems[0];
textBoxId.Text = row["id"].ToString();
textBoxName.Text = row["name"].ToString();
textBoxSpecialistIn.Text = row["specialist_in"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that your `ds.Tables` or `datagridDocSchedule.SelectedItems` is empty.
Debug your code and see which one is empty.